# Solve $xyp^2 -2p y^2+(2xy^2-x^3)=0$, $p = \frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $xyp^2 -2p y^2+(2xy^2-x^3)=0$ where $p = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$

**My attempt:**

> $$p = \frac{y^2 \pm \sqrt{y^4-2x^2y^3+x^4y}}{xy} \implies
>  \frac{xy \, dy-y^2 dx}{\sqrt{y^4-2x^2y^3+x^4y}}=\pm dx$$
>
> But this is not integrable. Please have a look at this and provide me some pointers on how to approach this problem.

Comment: just a quick glance... can you separate the $y$'s?  Looks like a quadratic in y

Comment: Is $p^2=\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2$, or $p^2=\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}$? I would assume the former, but some people do make the mistake of thinking the two are interchangeable.

Comment: $p = \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: I doubt there's a closed form for the differential-equation.